# Windows event code 4720

Tags: active-directory, windows-event-log

I observed a strange thing.
Why password not required field is enabled, even though we are providing passwords while creating a new user in active directory.

"
User Account Control:

```
    Account Disabled

    'Password Not Required' - Enabled

    'Normal Account' - Enabled

User Parameters:    -

SID History:        -

Logon Hours:        <value not set>
```

"

Answer (score 1):

I've seen account provisioning processes that do this to prevent the account creation from failing due to some password issue. But it should undo that after the account has been created.

Comment: I second that, you should see another event logged shortly thereafter setting some of the properties correctly.